# Python transpose explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

Playing around with Python dictionary comprehensions. Can you help me understand why this flips the key, value pairs around?  I'm not grokking why the value is also flipped.  (also it's 2am so.)  It's an interesting syntax.

```
capitals = {'USA': 'Washington, DC','France':'Paris','Italy':'Rome' } ​

capitals_flip = {capitals[key]: key for key in capitals}


capitals_flip

​ {'Paris': 'France', 'Rome': 'Italy', 'Washington, DC': 'USA'}
```

Comment: Do you understand how dict comprehensions work?

Comment: What is the issue here.? What you want to do.?

Comment: No, I guess not.  My problem is the second line such that the result in my mind is going USA:USA but it flips the value instead.  While this is the intended purpose and the above works, I'm not wholly understanding what this particular syntax is doing.  I'm trying docs but was hoping for a simple explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dict comprehension is syntax sugar that allows writing a loop that builds a dictionary much more compactly. The code

```
capitals_flip = {capitals[key]: key for key in capitals}
```

is more or less similar to

```
capitals_flip = {}
for key in capitals:
    capitals_flip[capitals[key]] = key
```

in other words the syntax is

```
new_dict = { <new_dict_key> : <new_dict_value>  for ... }
```

Consider the simpler example...

```
squares = { x: x*x for x in range(10) }
```

that builds a dictionary mapping a number to its square for all numbers from 0 to 9.

Comment: Yes I've used the numeric one before and didn't have a problem with it.  I think it just muddled the head when it flipped the key, values around.  But I see that it's just the same structure key:value and I'm mapping the value to a key.  Duh...  Silly brain.  Thank you!  That helped.